# How to reference one's resource output in another (Terraform)?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to reference Google's "google_cloud_run_service" url in spec.yml for "google_api_gateway_api_config". Is there a way to do it?

I've tried to do something like this
`x-google-backend: address: ${output.cloud_run_url.0.url}`
but to no avail

Comment: Please add the code you have to the question.

Comment: can mark the question as answered, i posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using template function like this,

```
  openapi_documents {
    document {
      path     = "config/openapi.yaml"
      contents = base64encode(templatefile("config/openapi.yaml", { cloudrun_service_url = google_cloud_run_service.rasbign.status[0].url }))
    }
  }
```

and then reference in yml file with `${cloudrun_service_url}`